# Android studio app crashes after registration screen

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Register user class:

```
    private void getUserInfo() {


    getUsersRef("stepgoal").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mSeries1 = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });

    getUsersRef("caloriegoal").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mSeries2 = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

The problem I have is while registering a user (using Firebase) after entering the user's details such as name, email, password for the registration screen, the app crashes. An already registered user is able to login successfully but for a new user it crashes before it reaches the EnterInfo class in which they should enter details about themselves such as weight, height etc.

Console Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.Conor.Ryan.GetFitOrDieFryin, PID: 16024
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "null"
        at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
        at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:164)
        at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:323)
        at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:306)
        at com.Conor.Ryan.GetFitOrDieFryin.LoginActivity$6.onDataChange(LoginActivity.java:189)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:179)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:75)
```

PS: My project is connected to two databases but I'm unable to delete the unused Cloud-Firestore one.

Any help would be great, this is my final year project for college.

[Firebase Database console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CpP5.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead replace those screenshots with the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark them up.

Comment: Done, I added the images as text and formatted it, cheers.

Comment: The error says that you're returning `"null"` (as a string), which is not a valid number. I'd log `Log.i("DATA", dataSnapshot.getValue()`), right before `mSeries1 = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()))` to see what data you're getting from the database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Just tried that, now getting "java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message". Do you think it's a code error or is it a database error ?

Comment: Given the mention of `println` it sounds like a code error, but please search for the error message as it's undoubtedly been asked before.

Comment: Will do, cheers